# Amazon LEX native email slot type does not recognize emails that ends in 4 digits

Tags: email, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-lex

It seems like Amazon.EmailAddress slot type has trouble recognizing emails that end in 4 or more numbers. For example `john2341@gmail.com`. It just automatically switches to the next intent and asks for an email repeatedly again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your own regex in the Lambda code validation and assign it to the email slot if it passes your regex.
That's what I have done.
And you will be validating the email address anyway after getting it in a slot, so it's better to have your own regex.
Hope it helps.